# How to append script tag to a div tag which is dynamically generate by javascript

Tags: javascript

I create a dynamical tag with id "video1" inside the static tag with id "videos":

```
document.getElementById("videos").innerHTML = '<div id="video1"></div>';
```

But when I want to append another script tag, I failed.

The following is my code to append that tag:

```
var s = document.createElement("script");
s.id = "scriptId"; //script tag's id
document.getElementById("video1").appendChild(s);
```

The above code works for static tag, but it doesn't work for the dynamical generated tag video1. So is there any way I can append a script tag to an another tag which is also dynamically generated by javascript?

Thanks.

Comment: Works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/38EU2/

Answer (score 0):

Instead, append it to the head:

```
var s = document.createElement("script");
s.id = "scriptId"; //script tag's id
document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(s);
```

You can also use `eval(s.text)` to evaluate the text content of the script

Comment: Is there any way can I append the tag inside "video1"? Since I want to use the API of Ooyala which uses script tag to generate the corresponding video. The place of script tag will decide the place of video. So I want to put that script tag in the specific place

Comment: Does it require that the script be in there? Because with most of these things, its just a declaration to a library, and then (either by calling an internal library function, or just by setting some variables) these settings are applied, the library is executed, then that has a set of `getElementById` like functions to find the containers (or other objects) to populate with its data. If the code is required inside the target element, any scripts with `src` to load the library can be put in the head, but any code can either be put in directly, or (like above) left in place and `eval`ed

Comment: Unfortunately, Ooyala seems just use the <script></script> tag to determine the position of the video. It will translate the script tag into a object tag in the same place used to play video.